# How can I print a string to the console without a newline at the end?

Tags: c#

My question is.

what is it you type when you want your answer next to your question in c#

I mean like this but you type the answer next to the question.

```
string product;

Console.WriteLine("What is the product you want?");

product = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Use Write() instead of WriteLine().

Answer (score 37):

Instead of using `Console.WriteLine()` use `Console.Write()`

Answer (score 4):

```
string product;

Console.Write("What is the product you want?");

product = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for `Console.Write("your text here");` rather than `Console.WriteLine("your text here");`

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to get rid of the newline.

`WriteLine` prints a newline.
`Write` doesn't.